# Directed Weighted Hyperedge

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I would like to make a hypergraph in latex with directed weighted hyperedges.
These look like: [image]

souce of image: https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.11.16.381566v1.full

I have no idea how to create these type of edges, with midarrows and weightes.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is your first post on TeX-SE, I'll give you some hints, but you should know that it is always better to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

[image: hyperedge?]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance=1cm and 8cm,
        >={Stealth[scale=3]}
        ]
    
        \begin{scope}[
            every node/.style=
                {
                circle,
                draw,
                minimum size=8mm,
                inner sep=0pt,
                font=\large,
                }
            ]
            \node (V1) {$v_1$};
            \node [below = of V1] (V2) {$v_2$};
            \path (V1) -- (V2) coordinate [midway] (V);
            \node [right = of V] (V4) {$v_4$};
            \node [above = of V4] (V3) {$v_3$};
            \node [below = of V4] (V5) {$v_5$};
        \end{scope}
        
        \path (V) -- (V4) coordinate [midway] (E);
        
        \draw (V1) to[out=-40,in=180,looseness=0.8] node[pos=0.3, above] {$w_1$} (E) to [out=0,in=-120] node[pos=0.7, above] {$w_3$} (V3) ;
        \draw (V2) to[out=40,in=180,looseness=0.8] node[pos=0.3, below] {$w_2$} (E) to [out=0,in=120] node[pos=0.7, below] {$w_5$} (V5);
        \draw [>-] (E) node [above = 3mm] {$e$} -- (V4) node [pos=0.9,above] {$w_4$};
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```